# trying to connecting jaserper server using jersy api throw exception?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jasperserver

When i am trying to connecting jaserper server using jersy api throw exception  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor

code bellow here

```
RestClientConfiguration configuration = new RestClientConfiguration("//localhost:80/jasperserver");
JasperserverRestClient client = new JasperserverRestClient(configuration);
//Session session = client.authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin");
OperationResult<InputStream> result = client
    .authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin")
    .reportingService()
    .report("/reports/samples/Cascading_multi_select_report")
    .prepareForRun(ReportOutputFormat.HTML, 1)
    //.parameter("Cascading_name_single_select", "A & U Stalker Telecommunications, Inc")
    .run();
InputStream report = result.getEntity();
```

The exact exception I am getting is below

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor.(Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorType;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorVisibility;ILjava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstantActiveDescriptor.(ConstantActiveDescriptor.java:111) at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstantActiveDescriptor.(ConstantActiveDescriptor.java:111)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getLocatorDescriptor(Utilities.java:795)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:69)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:230)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:121)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)  at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:117)     at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:207)    at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
>     at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
>     at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95)  at
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.(JerseyWebTarget.java:72)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:140)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:62)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.SessionStorage.init(SessionStorage.java:96)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.SessionStorage.(SessionStorage.java:56)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.JasperserverRestClient.authenticate(JasperserverRestClient.java:47)

[image: and jar details]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this operation without using any api. Just call the report with the parameters you want with REST call to your jasper server. This [guide](https://d2553lapexsdrl.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide_2.pdf) will help you.