# How to authenticate and authorize user to restricted resource in java

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have my web.xml file with restrictions to REST api using url `/rs/private/*/` like this:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>PRIVATE REST API</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/rs/private/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Have to be a USER</description>
            <role-name>USERS</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>userauth</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>USERS</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

From angular I am sending the Bearer+Token in the authorization http header:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', 'store', function ($q, $location, store) {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    if (store.get('jwt')) {
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + store.get('jwt');
                    }
                    return config;
                },
                'responseError': function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                        $location.path('/Login');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Request header in firefox:

```
Accept  
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvcnRoLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IlJUSCIsImV4cCI6MTQ1Mjk3Nzc4NiwiZW1haWwiOiJraXJpdGkuazk5OUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ
.SwyVMdweHgH3eQ-IYDUsjavAbUYPWQTSvdrIKMVQEzDTIsgvpWsoR13SJsV6kHrC_2uelBG0aSgExj794xe5yrK7VQ8J4yPRrXT
1EPf4LyABuHltHJNVtR_PRpPxcLZnP4GAQm-ozBVyHarsCpI9FINwhepY4_Lt51lU_EtDjI4
Host    
localhost:7070
Referer 
http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample13/
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
```

The problem is when I print the request headers in java I don't find authorization header that is sent from angular:

```
@Path("/public/loginResource")
public class LoginService {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public LoginService() {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response authenticateUser(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Credentials credentials) {

        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println(headerName);

            //PRINTS: host user-agent accept accept-language accept-encoding content-type referer content-length connection

        }
        String email = credentials.getEmail();
        String password = credentials.getPassword();
        String token = "";

        try {
            LoginDAO loginDao = new LoginDAO();
            if (loginDao.authenticate(email, password)) {
                TokenProvider jwtProvider = new TokenProvider();
                token = jwtProvider.getToken(email);
                Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
                response.put("token", token);
                return Response.ok(response).build();
            } else {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).type("text/plain").entity("Invalid Username or Password!").build();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).type("text/plain").entity("Error in Login Service web service class").build();
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is I would like to intercept every request and identify the user using the authorization header and token using some kind of filter.

There are 2 problems here:

1. request header doesn't contain `Authorization` header
2. How to intercept every request in java

Comment: about the second question, jersey has filter that can do that

Comment: As for your first question, I don't use `angularjs` but pure `js`, and looking at my code I would write `'Basic ' + store.get('jwt')` instead of `'Bearer ' + store.get('jwt')`. As for your second question, indeed there's many SO questions about `jersey` authentication filters. Take a look e.g. [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9666). Hope it helps

Comment: @lrnzcig jersey authentication filters uses jersey 2.0 and it has been a pain configuring 2.0 jars and all. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Sure it can be done @Satyadev, although I would not recommend it. I'll add an answer, give me 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comments.

As for your first question, I don't use `angularjs` but pure `js`, and looking at my code I would write `'Basic ' + store.get('jwt')` instead of `'Bearer ' + store.get('jwt')`.

As for your second question, indeed as in other comments there's many SO questions about jersey authentication filters. It is quite straight forward, you could take a look e.g. [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9666).

However, if you wanted to do it manually, you would have to do it in every service. (I don't really see why adding the filter would be an issue, but anyway).

It would be something like this (actually, the same kind of thing you would do in the filter):

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public <your_output_class> yourService(@Context final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

    String authentication = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (! authentication.startsWith("Basic ")) {
        throw new <your_exception>("Not authenticated");
    }
    authentication = authentication.substring("Basic ".length());
    String[] values = Base64.decodeAsString(authentication).split(":");
    if (values.length < 2) {
        throw new <your_exception>("Invalid syntax for username and password");
    }
    ...
```

And then you would check against the ddbb or whatever you have to store users and passwords.

Of course, you would need to put this in an utility method or something like that.

And finally, you have to be careful if you are using CORS, depending on your client you might have a `preflight` request with an empty header. No idea if `angularjs` does it or not. Just let me know.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried using `ContainerRequestContext` using jersey-server 2.0 jar and jersey-servlet-container 2.0 jar but there were so many errors and its not recognising restwebservice classes. I have also added `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` and `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` to web.xml file but still could not run the app :(

Comment: How are you deploying your server?

Comment: Using netbeans 8.02 with jee7 and apacheTomcat 8 in netbeans

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No I am not using maven..Manually added jars.

Comment: Its working fine with jersey 1.x versions until I required to have interceptors and filters where most examples I found was on jersey 2.0

Comment: Do you have `javax.ws.rs-api.jar`? I guess so, since this is really "core". Which version you are using?

Comment: I am using `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`

Comment: But then you should see `ContainerRequestContext`, which belongs to that jar `java.wx.rs-api`.... I'm sorry, it got a bit late in my timezone. I'll take a look tomorrow to see if you are still struggling, but I hope you find it soon, must be something silly you are missing.

Comment: I tried everything and ended up with this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor.(Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorType;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorVisibility;ILjava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/util/Map;)V at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstantActiveDescriptor.(ConstantActiveDescriptor.java:111) at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ConstantActiveDescriptor.(ConstantActiveDescriptor.java:111) at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getLocatorDescriptor(Utilities.java:795)`

Comment: Error like in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357394/trying-to-connecting-jaserper-server-using-jersy-api-throw-exception

Comment: Really last message for today: be careful when switching from jersey 1.0 to 2.0. You should not have any com.sun.jersey, all should be org.glassfish.jersey. If you have any com.sun.jersey, might be the source of your problems. Good night!